# How can I split a PDF by file size

Tags: python, pdf, split, pypdf

I need to split a PDF file into multiple PDFs which are smaller than 10 MB. I already managed to split the file into pages, but could not divide by the size of the destination file.

I did split the PDF into pages using the pypdf library:

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.add_page(page)
    with open(f"document-page{i}.pdf", "wb") as fp:
        writer.write(fp)
```

Comment: Because PDF files can share resources across pages and you won't know how well the resources will consolidate ahead of time, especially if you are subsetting fonts or have repeated images like a logo, you won't be able to just grab chunks of pages and know that they will result in a certain file size. You'll need to start with a single page and then add pages one by one, saving the file each time and then testing its size. Then delete the last page when the file size exceeds your maximum and resave the file, then start a new file with just the deleted page until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: Thaks for your help, @joelgeraci . I tried to use the os.path.getsize(filename) command, but couldn`t get it working. Any suggestion on this or maybe another way to get the file size?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple single answer as every PDF splitter will have a different take or set of user options.

Take a hypothetical case of a File that is 60% fonts 30% images and 10% text

say we have a compressed source file of 100 MB so if we split it into just the text with no images or Fonts we get 10 MB for all the pages, and that's what a lot of web optimisers may do/offer by drop font and image quality but in this scenario we would need each 10% of the file be evenly split so 1/10 of the images 1/10 of the fonts and 1/10th of the pages, however Images cannot be just 1/10th nor usually can fonts.

Often the output from split in to two would be 60 MB for fonts say 15 MB for images and 5 MB for half the text

Thus 100MB split in 2 = 80 MB + 80 MB thus the more its split the larger the storage space and transmittal resources required. Often defeating the aim of splitting, since if they are remerged at a destination they often become a 160MB file !!